# How to print the index of the first element of a sequence of the longest repeating number?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing a program for an assignment, which is:
Write a program that creates an int array of 20 elements, would ask the user how many tosses are required(1-20), fills the array with the result of tossing a number cube as many times as requested by the user, prints the values of the tosses horizontally then displays the longest run found
in the sequence of tosses.
For the above example the output would be if the user requested 18 tosses:

0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17

1  5  5  4  3  1  2  2  2  2  6  1 3  3  5  5  5 5

The longest run occurs at index 14.

I wrote the program for the first part, but I am stuck on trying to find the index of the longest run. This is my code so far:

```
const int SIZE = 20;

int main()
int arr[SIZE];
int numToss;
srand(time(0));

    cout << "How many tosses are required? Enter a value from 1 to 20: " << endl;
    cin >> numToss;
        while (numToss > SIZE || numToss < 1)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a value for the number of tosses greater than 1 and less than 20: " << endl;
            cin >> numToss;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < numToss; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = 1 + rand() % 6;
        cout << " " << arr[i];
    }
cout << endl;


int max_count = 0;
int length = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        int count = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
            count++;
        }
        if (count > max_count)
            max_count = count;
    }
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        int count=1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
            count++;
        }
        if (count == max_count)
          {
            max_count = arr[i];
            result = i;
            cout << "The longest run occurs at " << result << endl;
          }
    }

return 0;
```

It does not print correctly, how ca i fix this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How are you stuck?  How would you do it by hand?

Comment: That is where I am stuck I guess. I would do it by finding all the repeating numbers, then the most repeated number and then the index of that. But I am not sure how I would go about finding the index. Also, I feel that there is a simpler way to approach the problem, so any tips would be helpful

Comment: Iterate your values, and keep track of a `LongestSoFar` int variable and on which `index` it was found, something like `if current == previous && CurrentLongest > LongestSoFar, Keep Index and Increment LongestSoFar, else continue`. Each time you find longer with a different value, you have to save that `Longest` and replace the saved index with the new index.

Comment: Can I see an example? Sorry, it's hard to understand especially since I am new to arrays and they are a little confusing.